# Mysql select rows with the same value

Tags: mysql

I have the following table in a mysql a database:

```
+-------+-----------+------------+
| id    | object_nr | object_nr2 |
+-------+-----------+------------+
| 24567 | 04        | 11         | 
| 24568 | 04        | 11         | 
| 24569 | 04        | 11         | 
| 24570 | 04        | 41         | 
+-------+-----------+------------+
```

The columns object_nr and object_nr2 have the same values in the rows with id 24567,245678 and 24569.

I would like to select only these three rows.

The row with id 24570 will not be included in this selection.

How to write a select statement that can do that?

Comment: Have you try or google anything?

Comment: Your question says **equal** but the expected result says **reverse**.

Comment: No, no reverse. I changed to 11 to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM TableName T1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM TableName T2
       WHERE T1.object_nr=T2.object_nr
       AND T1.object_nr2=T2.object_nr2)>1
```

Result:

```
ID      OBJECT_NR   OBJECT_NR2
24567   4           11
24568   4           11
24569   4           11
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6c7c/1).

Comment: I think the OP means row-by-row, not column-to-column

Comment: @Strawberry: Yeah!! you are right!! Edited my answer. Added a working fiddle. Thanks.

Comment: This works fine, thanks! I have another question: I have the following select statement to get the table in my first question: select id,object_nr,object_nr2 from TableName where item = 8. I would like to merge this sql statement with the one you have proposed to get the final result. How do I do that?

Comment: I found the solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from yourtable where object_nr = object_nr2
```

Comment: Using this query have you got expected result. 04=40

Comment: The example contradicts the question. Which part should he answer?

Comment: Yeah actually, considering the complexity of this statement, I'm guessing the OP had the good SQL but read or inserted to fast his data and tought the 04 were 40... Because in the question he is actually asking for same value but the desired output aren't same.